# How can I retrive data from my settings collection before anything else is loaded?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo collection called Settings. It stores some settings like API keys. Those settings should be adjustable within the application, without accessing the server.

Those settings need to be loaded and be present on the client before anything else. Because in case of the API-keys, the API will crash if the key is not defined before the API starts to load.

I can not use settings.json, because as far as I know, you can not change them during the runtime. Settings.json can only be hardcoded on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a concept misunderstanding here. The easy solution is to check if the api keys are loaded and then run the dependent code. In that way, the app will not crash.

Answer (score 1):

Use callback to make your code synchronous.

Try something as below, which may solve your problem:-

```
Meteor.methods({
'getApiKey': function () {
    return Settings.findOne().key //there is only one entry so far
 } });

//
function setKey(callback)
{
   Meteor.call('getApiKey', function (err, result) {
   if (err) console.log(err);

      Session.set('key', result);
      callback(err);
   });
}

//Wait for the `getApiKey` to complete, use callback.
setKey(function(err)
{
     var apiKey = Session.get('key'); //Set the key in the callback function
})
```

EDIT:-

Try this instead:-

```
Meteor.methods({
'getApiKey': function () {
    return Settings.findOne().key //there is only one entry so far
 } });

  var apiKey;
   Meteor.call('getApiKey', function (err, result) {
   if (err) console.log(err);

      Session.set('key', result);
      apiKey = Session.get('key'); 
      console.log(apiKey);
   });
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Seems like it did. But I do not fully understand the code. Also I am not sure how to use apiKey outside of setKey(). Instead I put my code which uses apiKey inside of setKey(), but it seems like that is not the right way. Could you please explain?

Comment: I have edited my answer with one more way of doing what you want. Let me know it is working or not and if doing this way is fine for you?

Comment: In case of edit, the apiKey is defined only within the call. Outside the Meteor.call it has no value. This does not work.

Comment: In that case I could use just: Meteor.call('getApiKey', function (err, result) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    GoogleMaps.load({key: result});
}); So the key is used within the meteor call. But I wanted to use it outside, since it feels to be the more right way.

Comment: The first method is what I can think as a solution as of now. As your code is asynchronous, accessing `apiKey` outside, without any `callback` will not work.